# BigCommerce Stencil Blank Screen

Tags: bigcommerce

Losing my will to live with this one.

Went to start up my BigCommerce project and the localhost URL is just showing a blank screen. Zero errors in command line or in the browser console so I have absolutely no clue why it's just a blank screen.

Running Stencil Version 5.2.2
NVM 14.20.0
NPM 6.14.17

Not really sure what else to share, as I said, I'm getting no errors anywhere to give me a clue as to what's going on. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Losing my will to live with this one...lol...
you're not alone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I have momentarily downgrade to stencil-cli 5.2.0

I uninstalled and reinstall @ 5.2.0 e.g.

```
npm uninstall -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli

npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli@5.2.0
```

This isn't a fix I know, but might get you working in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Honestly, I hate BigCommerce sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be some bugs in the newer versions of stencil-cli.

https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues/994

Downgrading appears the solution for the moment.

Edit:

Bigcommerce are pushing an upgrade to their PHP app today to fix this